In the UK, how do scientists address each other?
Let's say you have a PhD, and they have a PhD, and you are familiar with each others' work, but you never met personally. Would you address them as "Dear Dr. Smith" in an email, or "Dear John"?
A further source of awkwardness: Suppose you are addressing several people at the same time, and some do not have a PhD yet, do you write "Dear Dr. Williams, Mr. Johnson and Dr. Smith"?

This depends more on the field than anything else. Please specify what field you have in mind.

With great vengeance and furious anger?

What ho, fellow boffin.

I only call my PhD friends Dr XX whenever they do a big fuckup, to gently mock them. Otherwise its closer to "mate".

I have avoided this question during my entire PhD by starting my email by just "Hello,"

@JackRed It's better than "Dear," without a name. That's for sure.


Dear Barbara (if I may),
Xyz.
Kind Regards, Carla

Don't ever Mr., Ms. or Mrs. (urgh) anyone because it gets gross quickly for anyone who is not cis, and you don't want to assume their gender.

(+1) I share your dislike of the gendered modes of address, and avoid them myself. From a purely descriptive perspective however, they are (unfortunately) still commonly used.

"it's gets gross quickly for anyone who is not a cis male" Pardon me, but, I would like to make you aware that this exactly is gender discrimination of cis males.

@Hjan Most cis males I'm acquainted with do not find this gross (though a minority do). When you're explicitly talking about gendered aspects of societal convention, I don't think it's discrimination to acknowledge the fact it affects (typical members of) different groups differently. (I'm not sure it's important to include that information in this answer, but that's another matter entirely.)

@wizzwizz4 surely if it is "gross" it is equally gross for anyone who isn't cis. I don't understand why cis males should be singled out in particular. I am sure you have seen may cis females, for example, understandably objecting to being called "Mr". I edited the relevant part of the answer since I honestly think this was just a typo or editing error (also confirmed by the errant "it's").

@terdon Mrs / Miss, presumably. See Wikipedia. (I'd have edited out the entire qualifier, just leaving "it gets gross quickly".)

I feel like the advice at the end is way too categorical. I understand that the point is to avoid misgendering people, which is excellent. I'm not sure about the seeming implication that no transgender person would ever want to be referred to as "Mr.", "Mrs." or "Ms." More to the point, though, while if one has no additional information, one should clearly avoid assuming a gender, it's quite possible to have information on someone's pronouns or even their preferred honorific directly from their webpages, their papers, their email signature, their talks, or just from knowing them.

Also, I see that "cis" was previously "cis male," and the seeming implication from that version of the statement that being called "Ms." is perceived as gross by all cisgender (and transgender) women is facially incorrect.

@wizzwizz4 - I think it's a good and necessary point about avoiding misgendering people, but (initially) framed in such a categorical way as to suggest that no binary transgender person would ever feel comfortable being referred to with any gendered honorific, no women want to be referred to as "Ms." or "Mrs.", and perhaps even that one should avoid gendered honorifics even when one knows that someone would prefer them. (I personally would like gendered honorifics and pronouns to disappear, but I'm not going to do that by ignoring the expressed personal preferences of those who use them).

@terdon I think your edit is misunderstanding the meaning of the original guidance. The overlapping problems are 1) misgendering, particularly for trans people (hence the mention of "cis"), and 2) for all women, determining their title of address based on their marital status (gross). Though certainly not everyone is equally offended or equally okay with these labels, and though certainly cis men can have a problem with the system as well as anyone else, the point is that "Mr./Ms./Mrs." only "works" consistently for addressing someone who is a cis male where "Mr." most clearly describes them.

When it comes to titles, there's an easy solution, see what title is used on their staff page or in the staff directory and use that. If they get offended over it that's not your fault, that's the university's problem.

@BryanKrause - Ms. was specifically created as an equivalent of Mr. for women that did not signal marital status, though, relative to the Mrs./Miss dichotomy. And plenty of women use it for themselves regardless of marital status. The implication that "Ms." is universally rejected is part of what makes the categorical assertion there less than perfectly helpful, with the other half being that someone could easily get the impression that binary transgender people universally don't use gendered titles.

Well, and the fact that its wording is so broad as to either not contemplate the possibility that some (really, many) people actually both want to be referred to with gender titles and convey which ones are correct through various means, or to imply that even they should not be referred to with gendered titles despite their personal preferences.

@Obie2.0 It was popularized for that use but it's actual use goes back further as abbreviation for Miss; not everyone is comfortable with it.

@BryanKrause - I think it originated as an abbreviation of "Mistress" in a period when this term was not tied to marital status. That's kind of beside the point, though, because there's a lot of space between "not everyone is comfortable with it" (true) and "never use it with anyone" (what the answer perhaps unintentionally implies). Not everyone is comfortable being called "she," either, including many cisgender and transgender men, many non-binary people, and even some cisgender women, but declaring "never call anyone 'she'" would also be less than fully correct.

@BryanKrause - The fundamental issue with the assertion in the answer is that, less than encouraging the cautious and respectful approach of not using any gendered titles unless you know what someone prefers, it seems (again, perhaps inadvertently) to suggest the approach of never using any gendered titles, regardless of what someone prefers.

I accepted this answer, because I liked the (if I may) suggestion. But I don't really know what the social norms in the UK are.

@BryanKrause the original version was "Don't ever Mr., Ms. or Mrs. (urgh) anyone because it's[sic] gets gross quickly for anyone who is not a cis male". That sentence doesn't make sense, and the typo suggested it was a remnant of an incomplete edit prior to posting. In any case, it doesn't make sense to say that using Ms or Mrs gets "gross" if you are not a cis male. Had the sentence only been about "Mr" maybe that would work—although, obviously, at least some trans males would be more than comfortable with Mr—but with the addition of the female versions the sentence was nonsensical.

@terdon If you're not a male, then the Mr/Ms/Mrs system involves choosing your honorific based on marital status. That's the sense.

@BryanKrause I mean, feel free to edit as you wish, but the OP focused specifically on cis males as though everyone else is happy to be misgendered. And Mr vs Ms (nobody really uses Mrs anymore and the OP added an "urgh" for that one anyway) has nothing to do with marital status.

The hurdles to address someone by first name are very small in British academia. Being mutually acquainted with each others papers, or eg being introduced via a common acquaintance, are definitely enough to make using the first name acceptable.
If you are using a formal mode of address, you should get it right though. That indeed means using "Prof" for professors (associate professors are not professors in the UK), using Dr for everyone else with a PhD, and Mr/Ms for those without.

using the first name acceptable --- Unless in a movie or TV show, where it seems even close colleagues ALWAYS refer to each other as Doctor or Professor. This is one of those "Hollywood things" that I don't know whether the people involved simply don't know any better (presumably these people never overhead their college/university professors talking among themselves when these people were walking through hallway corridors to their classes or at any other time) or whether these people are doing this because they think this is what viewers expect (who also presumably never . . .).

As with all things, there are subtlies. So the hurdles to using first names are small in British academia, but they are not non-existiant. If you have no connection at all to someone, I would use Dr./Prof. I would also use title-lastname on my first email to someone, then probably revert to first name after that.

@IanSudbery "I would also use title-lastname" -- if you have no connection, or regardless?

@MWB I might well use it regardless if its my first ever email to someone, although not if I knew them very well. Also important here is respective seniority. I would definately always use formal address for my first ever email to someone more senior than me.

@DaveLRenfro It's not just academia. I've been on a first-name basis with every boss, colleague, and customer I've had in the US computer industry for over 40 years. Yet Hollywood usually shows much more formality than I've ever experienced.

Conversely, when I was an undergrad I called all my professors "professor ___", even when I knew they probably would have preferred their first names. Was it a sign of respect? Sort of but that's not the real reason. I'm just a big Futurama fan and I get a kick out of calling anyone professor.

Generally, "Hi John".
If you're in a formal setting, they're particularly accomplished, and it's the first time you've met them, maybe "Doctor X" but that would generally be the exception and, in my experience they will almost always tell you to use their first name.
If you're emailing, having never spoken to them before, Dr X might be more appropriate for the initial email and then go with whatever they respond with from there.
Now, you might get the odd stuffy one but in my experience next to nobody cares and most people are more than happy with just being called their name.

This is the correct answer in my experience. If I was emailing someone particularly senior and famous I would maybe look up their title, otherwise I'm going to go with "Hi firstname". The thing that throws me is when someone signs their email with a particularly informal feeling name (e.g. Deborah signs an email "Debs"), but I make myself respond with whatever name they signed with even if it feels weirdly informal.

Considering that the first contact is almost always e-mail, and the OP asks explicitly for a situation where they are familiar with the person's work but have never actually met, I would almost always go for "Dr X" or "Prof X" (whichever is correct, as listed on their staff page) for first contact. While true that 99% of the time, it will indeed converge to "Hi John" after a single round of e-mails, in my experience cold e-mails starting with "Hi Firstname" tend to be spam so I'm not particularly endeared to them.

If you've never communicated with an academic before, best to play it safe and address them either as Dr. Lastname or Prof. Lastname. Be absolutely sure to check which title they use by going on to the university or institution website (professor is an earned title in the UK, and most academics are not professors). If they don't have a PhD (they might be a student) then usual title conventions apply.
Include your full name (including your title) in your message if communicating in writing. If they address you with your first name and/or don't use their title in their response, then you can safely assume, at least in writing and one-on-one conversations, that you're on first name terms now, and should from then on communicate as such. I find most academics tend to prefer first name terms nowadays.
One important thing to note is if you're conversing with them with an audience. Some academics will be happy for you to be causal with them privately or with a group of other academics, or perhaps even PhD students, but they will be bothered if you don't use their title when introducing them or conversing with them with a group of undergraduates listening in, for example.

"Include your full name" -- to clarify, are you referring to the email signature, or the message itself? Here in the US, at least, I finish the message with my first name as a signal that it's OK to use it.

@MWB In the signature generally.

Include your full name (including your title) in your message if communicating in writing Signing off with your title may indicate to the other party you want to be addressed by it, which in a UK context would be rather unusual but they will be bothered if you don't use their title when introducing them or conversing with them with a group of undergraduates listening in, for example. In the UK anyone who was bothered by this would come off as having absurd delusions of grandeur, given undergrads more often than not use first names with lecturers.

@MJeffryes If you're concerned about your first  point, then you can use your full name or first name without your title and then include a signature block below with your title. That's pretty common in emails. As for your second point, I think it is important to remember that firstly UK academics are a very diverse bunch and may have come from cultures with different expectations of formality, and secondly it's not nessecarily about ego, it could be seen as showing the undergrads formal etiquette (which might help if they interact with other academics outside the UK).

@Crazymoomin On the second point, I just don't think your answer is actually grounded in how UK academics behave. Your answer is generic and not actually applicable to this country. That is, it would not be a reasonable expectation for anyone working in a UK university to have, and is not one anyone would bother to concern themself with catering for (unless I suppose they were directly asked to, but if someone did ask me that I'd think they were incredibly pompous, and I suspect so would the vast majority of my colleagues).

@MJeffryes I am a PDRA at a well-known UK university. We have academics from all over the world from different countries and cultures, and some of them prefer more formal communication to others. You don't know, so you shouldn't assume. Even some British academics can be a bit fussy about it. My English PI, for example, we are on first name terms in private settings and in small project meetings, but in some group meetings he addresses everyone by their title (if they have one), including when introducing himself.

Actually I think this the best response here; it covers all the points and mentions to check their staff page which will usually hint at a correct title. I'm also an academic in the UK, I'm somewhere in between in how I'd like to be addressed, have colleagues from all over this range of behaviours, and I don't think any of them have absurd delusions of grandeur. Which is why I think this answer (use Title Lastname to introduce, and give the person a chance to offer their first name themself) is right on point

For example, as a module coordinator, I will make sure to introduce the module team (myself and another academic; especially the other academic) as Title Lastname (and I'll practice pronouncing his last name the day before). I think both him and me tell students to address us by our first name, as our last ones are difficult for English speakers, especially if they are polite in their communication. However, if I get an email addressed to "Dear Sir" (I am female, and this happens often), I don't feel particularly inclined to offer to be on a first-name basis with that undergrad.
